# Erro ao tentar dar update em um dialog PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, java-ee, primefaces

Tenho um botão que fica dentro de uma coluna em uma dataTable, esse botão abre um `dialog` que contém uma tabela com alguns dados. Porém quando tento dar um `update=":frmPrin:dialogParecer"` da o seguinte erro na página:

> Cannot find component for expression ":frmPrin:parecer" referenced
>   from "frmPrin:j_idt30:reembolsoTable:0:j_idt52".

Essa minha `dataTable` fica dentro de um `tabView`. E quando eu deixo o `update=":frmPrin"` funciona, porém atualiza todo o formulário. Como posso atualizar apenas o `dialog`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confira o nome que vc colocou no update, pois na mensagem diz que não encontrou :frmPrin:parecer e segundo sua postagem o o correto seria update=":frmPrin:dialogParecer", sou seja está faltando o dialog antes de Parecer.

> Achei que o problema tinha sido resolvido porém quando entrei no hoje
>   no sistema começou o erro novamente, eu estava fazendo da seguinte
>   forma: update="frmPrin:j_idt30:parecer adicionando esse j_idt30 que vi
>   no modo desenvolvedor do navegador, porém hoje esse id já mudou, ou
>   seja ele fica mudando. O que pode ser isso?

Esse j_idt30 é um id dinâmico, então o ideal é você colocar no update o id que vc denominou para o componente, talvez se vc posta o código da página fica mais fácil analisar o erro.

Comment: Conferi e o nome está correto

Comment: Continua retornando a mesma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Sim, eu meio que consegui contornar o problema usando um <p:remoteCommand> que faz o update e depois eu chamo ele ao abrir o dialog

Comment: Bom, não sei como ficou seu código, mas se atende ao seu problema é o que importa. Qualquer coisa posta o código para podermos analisar com mais precisão.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado por tentar ajudar. Vou postar como resolvi o problema daqui a pouco.

Comment: Achei que o problema tinha sido resolvido porém quando entrei no hoje no sistema começou o erro novamente, eu estava fazendo da seguinte forma: `update="frmPrin:j_idt30:parecer` adicionando esse `j_idt30` que vi no modo desenvolvedor do navegador, porém hoje esse id já mudou, ou seja ele fica mudando. O que pode ser isso?

Comment: Esse j_idt30 é um id dinâmico, então o ideal é você colocar no update o id que vc denominou para o componente, talvez se vc posta o código da página fica mais fácil analisar o erro.

Comment: Era isso que tava faltando mesmo, faltou eu colocar um ID no `tabView`. Obrigado pela ajuda, edite sua pergunta com esse ultimo comentário para que possa ajudar mais pessoas